# Primary and foreign key

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

Can we apply two primary keys in a table in anyway?

Comment: You can define multiple foreign keys on a table.

Comment: I have provided an answer but this question is far too vague - you need to provide more information.  I was in two minds whether to give you a down vote or close it.  Hence the downvote

Comment: You can have several Unique Constraints, but only one Primary Key.

Comment: you can only have one primary key, but multiple fields can make up the primary key.

Comment: you can also have ALTERNATE KEYS which may act in the same way as a primary key. - i agree poor question. - spared the OP the downvote however.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an Employee. This employee has an EmployeeType of some sort (one foreign key). And this Employee has an EmployeeDepartment connection (another foreign key).

If I understand your question correctly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  Although I can't be sure this is the correct answer for you as your question is so vague.

[Foreign Key information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933117(SQL.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many foreign keys as you like. Just add them.

When I want to create a constraint to enforce the foreign key, I create a diagram with the tables, and drag a connection from the primary key to the foreign key.

Depending on how you use the keys in queries, you might want to create an index for it also.

Answer (score 0):

there should be one primary key but there can be more than 1 foreign key if the table has references to other tables

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many as you like

Normally one of the is called the "Primary Key" and the other equivalents are called ["Surrogate Keys"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) or "Synthetic Keys"

The main "Primary Key" is the natural one if it exists (e.g. existing customer number) , or a unique row identifier if no suitable natural key. This is the main key used to form foreign key relationships, but any other equivalent primary key can be used if required. This is generally not done to avoid confusion